# Not all braintree HostedFields methods available for typescript?

Tags: typescript, braintree, braintree-sandbox, braintree-javascript

I'm using Braintree Sandbox in my ReactJs project with typescript.

According to [Braintree Docs](https://braintree.github.io/braintree-web/3.20.1/HostedFields.html#focus) for focus, a field can be focused using the `.focus()` method.

```
hostedFieldsInstance.focus('number', function (focusErr) {
  if (focusErr) {
    console.error(focusErr); 
  }
});
```

Issue: In my typeScript file, hostedFieldsInstance is not showing the`.focus()` method as a valid method. Im getting the following error:

`Property 'focus' does not exist on type 'HostedFields'.ts(2339)`

VS Code is also suggesting only few existing braintree methods but not `.focus()`:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[The TS definitions from DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/da860cab5df906d7a1c5b18c4a507a4a6dd98dd8/types/braintree-web/modules/hosted-fields.d.ts) don't include that function, but that doesn't mean that you cannot call it regardless. Your options include:

- Bypassing the TS compiler check in that case (`(hostedFields as any).focus(...)`)
- Writing your own type definitions for BrainTree, importing the existing ones from DefinitelyTyped and overriding them to add what you need
- Waiting for the BrainTree TS rewrite (see [this comment](https://github.com/braintree/braintree-web/issues/429#issuecomment-708454381))